# Problems with Odeint : numerical precision integration

Tags: precision, odeint

I'm having trouble with odeint function. It looks like something on the accuracy, but I'm not sure . I am generating time series for the Rossler attractor according to code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def rossler(vec, time, a, b, c):
x = vec[0]
y = vec[1]
z = vec[2]

eq. dif. de rossler
xd = -y -z
yd = x + a*y
zd = b + (x-c)*z

return(xd, yd, zd)


#BEGIN
#constantes de rossler
a = 0.1
b = 0.1
c = 6

#condicoes iniciais
init = np.array([2., 3., 4.])

N_time = 80000
t =np.linspace(0,1000,N_time)

vec_xyz_com_transiente = odeint(rossler, init, t, args = (a, b, c) )

tam = len(vec_xyz_com_transiente[:,0])
inicio = int(0.9*tam)
vec_xyz = vec_xyz_com_transiente[inicio:,:].copy()
```

The output should be a set of three time series displaying period 2 (the theory justifies this fact ) but did not notice it in my data. What might be happening?